# VBA how to determine the number of rows in a variable defined by a range stored in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, count, row

The goal is to define a variable, in this case C, as the number of rows in a range stored in an array. The inputs (1-4) are defined using the "Defined Name" function in EXCEL. The (.Rows.Count) appears to only work with the range function. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I can explain what I'm trying to do in more detail if need be.

```
Private Sub Pop_Click()
      Dim INPUT1 As Variant: Set INPUT1 = Range("INPUT1")
    Dim INPUT2 As Variant: Set INPUT2 = Range("INPUT2")
    Dim INPUT3 As Variant: Set INPUT3 = Range("INPUT3")
    Dim INPUT4 As Variant: Set INPUT4 = Range("INPUT4")
    Dim INPUTS As Variant: INPUTS = Array(0, INPUT1, INPUT2, INPUT3, INPUT4)
    
    Dim C As Variant: C = INPUTS(1).Rows.Count

    Dim SR1 As Integer: SR1 = 18
    Dim SC1 As Integer: SC1 = 4
    Dim ER1 As Integer: ER1 = 19
    Dim EC1 As Integer: EC1 = 15

    Range(Cells(SR1, SC1), Cells(ER1, EC1)) = INPUTS(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Dim C As Long: C = UBound(INPUTS(1), 1)`.

Comment: ^^^^^^ the reason that INPUT1 is a Variant Array not a Range. If you want to be a Range use SET  statement.

Comment: @Black and @VBasic2008. I tried this and I get a "Type mismatch" error.    `Dim INPUT1 As Variant: Set INPUT1 = Range("INPUT1").Value  Dim INPUT2 As Variant: Set INPUT2 = Range("INPUT2").Value  Dim INPUT3 As Variant: Set INPUT3 = Range("INPUT3").Value  Dim INPUT4 As Variant: Set INPUT4 = Range("INPUT4").Value  Dim INPUTS As Variant: Set INPUTS = Array(0, INPUT1, INPUT2, INPUT3, INPUT4)  Dim C As Long: C = UBound(INPUTS(1), 1)  `

Comment: With Set you cannot use value `Set INPUT1 = Range("INPUT1")`

Comment: @Black Thanks. The Dim C line above still results in a "Type mismatch" error. Any ideas?

Comment: @BrianBodzenta can you please edit your question with your updated code? (so its easier to check for errors)

Comment: You joined the two workarounds. If you use the SET than don't change the Dim C line.

Comment: @Shrotter I updated the question with my new code.

Comment: @Black Thanks the code works now, but of course I now have new issues.

Comment: @Black When using SET to define the range variables the 'Range(Cells(SR1, SC1), Cells(ER1, EC1)) = INPUTS(1)' line at the bottom of my code no longer works. The ranges are the same size/shape and there is no error but the information in defined name "Input 1" will not paste to the specified range. The cells are blank. I suspect this is because the .Value is no longer used. **NVM probelem solved! THANK YOU**

Comment: In the last row, the range sizes must match, and the source must be the range values. `Range(Cells(SR1, SC1), Cells(ER1, EC1)).Resize(INPUTS(1).Rows.Count, INPUTS(1).Columns.Count) = INPUTS(1).Value` or `Cells(SR1, SC1).Resize(INPUTS(1).Rows.Count, INPUTS(1).Columns.Count) = INPUTS(1).Value`